# what is the output of the following C code and how does it work?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h> 

void main() 
{ 
    while(1) 
    { 
        if(printf("%d",printf("%d"))) 
            break; 
        else 
            continue; 
    } 
}
```

How is it possible to have a statement in the `if` clause?

The output I get is `Undefined values`

Comment: "What is the output..." can't you run it and see for yourself? Also, where did this code come from? Because it *doesn't* work (the code is invalid, `printf("%d")` requires another argument).

Comment: The program above invokes **Undefined Behaviour**. According to the rules of the language it can do anything, eg it can transfer the funds in your bank account to mine :)

Comment: @dvnrrs well, "doesn't work" is hell of a claim. It will do something. What it would be, however, is unspecified :-)

Comment: @keltar Correct, so whatever you *think* it should do, it is not guaranteed to do *that* (that's what "undefined behavior" means). Therefore I think saying "it doesn't work" is on pretty solid ground since "working" implies it is guaranteed to do something that you expect it to do.

Answer (score 1):

How come is a Statement in if clause?

`printf` returns the number of characters to be printed. Any Non-zero value in C can be evaluated as `true`, you can use the return value to test the `if` condition.

Beside all, your program invokes undefined behavior because you are not passing an argument for `%d` in inner `printf`.